# AWS Cognito OAuth/Token endpoint returning "invalid_request"

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm currently rebuilding an application and I'm encountering an issue with the AWS Cognito OAuth/Token endpoint. My user pool requires client secret keys. The endpoint consistently returns an "invalid_request" error.

Here is the code snippet

```
let response: TResponse;
        const { code, redirect_uri } = loginDto;
        let { lang_id, country_id } = loginDto;

        const origin = `${this.cognito_domain}/oauth2/token`;
        let body;
        const form = new URLSearchParams();
        form.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
        form.append('client_id', this.clientId);
        form.append('redirect_uri', redirect_uri);
        form.append('code', code);

        let credentials = btoa(`${this.clientId}:${this.clientSecret}`);
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
            },
        };
        try {
            const result = await axios.post(origin, form.toString(), config);
            console.log(result);
        } catch (error) {
            response = {
                status: 401,
                succeeded: false,
                error: `Fail: ${error} `,
            };
            console.log(error.response.data);
            return response;
        }
```

I have already ensured that the AWS Cognito user pool and client ID are correctly configured. However, despite these efforts, I'm still facing the "invalid_request" error when attempting to access the OAuth/Token endpoint. I have double-checked the client credentials, and verified the callback url and they are correct. The authorization flow I'm using is OAuth2.